# How can I hide/unhide a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm playing around with jquery and made a form that submits information without a page refresh but in the [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) I followed it must first display a form for people to edit but what I want to do is slightly different.

I want to display a users profile page and then have a little edit link beside each item which causes a text field to appear if they click edit. I believe I can submit the form without a refresh but how can I have a form appear when the 'edit' button is clicked without refreshing?

Any idea of how I can accomplish this or even better what should I be searching to learn how to do this? I went through the sample items on jquery site and none of them seemed to hide/unhide by clicking.

Comment: The jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` methods are probably two of the most-used cosmetic effects in the entire API; I'm sure you'll find tonnes of examples with a quick web search, knowing the function names.

Comment: Searching for "jquery in-place editing" is probably a good place to start. There are many tutorials out there on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll look into those methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how I'd handle the concept, I'd follow it up with posting and validation and all else a little server-side scripting etc, but this can act as your stepping stone overall. Pretty much all you got to remember is javascript/jquery is all smoke and mirrors since its all handled client-side you essentially need to work with what you have on screen be it hidden or otherwise. 
In this case you have 2 elements one showing by default while the other hides, you make a logic that hides one over the other when one is chosen, and do what you need to respectively with either.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="container">
      <div id="storedvalue"><span>Hello</span> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="editvalue">edit</a>]</div>
      <div id="altervalue" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="changevalue" id="changevalue" value="Hello"> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="savevalue">save</a>]</div>
   </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#editvalue').click(function(e){$('#storedvalue').hide();$('#altervalue').show();});
$('#savevalue').click(function(e){
   var showNew = $('#changevalue').val();
   $('#altervalue').hide();
   $('#storedvalue').show();
   $('#storedvalue span').text(showNew);
});
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BxpSF/)

Answer (score 1):

A HTML form cannot be submitted without refreshing the page. However, JavaScript (and by extension, jQuery) can be used to submit similar GET or POST requests. You can also use jQuery's `.append` method to insert the necessary markup to create inputs on-the-fly. jQuery can also be used to access the values that have been inputted to the field (usually done by id).

Something I am working on *simmilar* to what you need:

(this particular code takes some input from a visible form, and aggregates it into an invisible one for later use)

```
jQuery('#submitButton').click(function(){

  jQuery('#prev_request').append('<input type="hidden" name="sort_order" value="'+jQuery("input[@name=sort_order]:checked").val()+'" />');
  jQuery('#prev_request').append('<input type="hidden" name="sort_by" value="'+ jQuery("#sort_by option:selected").val() +'" />');


});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest thing to do would be something like this:

HTML

```
<form id="form1" style="display: none;">
</form>
<a id="editButton" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a>
<a id="closeButton" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;">Close</a>
```

JavaScript (be sure to include jQuery on your page)

```
$(function() {
    $("#editButton").click(function() {
        $("#form1").show();
        $("#editButton").hide();
        $("#closeButton").show();
    });

    $("#closeButton").click(function() {
        $("#form1").hide();
        $("#editButton").show();
        $("#closeButton").hide();
    });
});
```

It's also easy to add an expanding transition effect with the `show()` and `hide()` methods.  Simply pass the desired transition duration to the function (in milliseconds) like this:

```
$("#form1").show(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lostsoul,

I would utilize an asp DataGrid inside of an UpdatePanel control:

.ascx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="yourUPpanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
       <asp:DataGrid ID="yourDG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" AllowSorting="False" AllowPaging="False" EnableViewState="false" onItemCommand="yourDG_CellClick">
          <FooterStyle CssClass="cssFooter"></FooterStyle>
          <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="CssAltItem"></AlternatingItemStyle>
          <ItemStyle CssClass="cssGridItem"></ItemStyle>
          <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader"></HeaderStyle>
       </asp:DataGrid>
       <asp:Panel ID="yourAdditionalStuff" runat="server" Visible="false">
         <table>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="yourTXT" runat="server" Width="100px"/>
             </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
       </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.vb

```
Public Sub yourUPpanel_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles yourUPpanel.Load

        If cnADO Is Nothing Then blahblah.getConnection("yourserver", cnADO) 'whatever the case may be here
        Try

            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

            Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand
            cmd3.Connection = cnADO
            cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd3.CommandText = "SP to populate GRID"     'whatever the case may be here
            daPeople = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            daPeople.SelectCommand = cmd3

            If yourDG.Columns.Count <= 0 Then
                Dim btnc As New ButtonColumn
                btnc.ButtonType = ButtonColumnType.LinkButton
                btnc.HeaderText = "Edit"
                btnc.DataTextField = "primarykey"
                btnc.DataTextFormatString = "<img border='0' src=" & ResolveUrl("~/images/edit.gif") & ">"         'whatever the case may be here
                btnc.CommandName = "Edit"
                btnc.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
                yourDG.Columns.Add(btnc)

                Dim bc As New BoundColumn

                bc = New BoundColumn
                bc.DataField = "sqlColumnName"
                bc.HeaderText = "First"
                yourDG.Columns.Add(bc)

            End If

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            yourDG.Fill(dt)
            yourDG.DataSource = dt
            yourDG.DataBind()

            'lbtnEditAddPerson.Visible = True
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            If Not cnADO Is Nothing Then
                If cnADO.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    cnADO.Close()
                End If
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub



 Protected Sub yourDG_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs)

        Dim cmd As String = e.CommandName.ToString.ToUpper
        If cmd.ToUpper = "EDIT" Then
            Using cnADO As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourserver").ToString) 'whatever the case may be here
                Using scmd As New SqlCommand("", cnADO)
                    scmd.CommandText = "YOURTEXTHERE"

                    Using dr As SqlDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader()
                        If dr.Read Then
                            'fill textbox for load
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            yourAdditionalStuff.Visible = True


        ElseIf cmd.ToUpper = "ANOTHERCOMMAND" Then 'if you want to...allows for extensibility (would need another column tho)

        End If
End Sub
```

Note that this is a *framework*, but should be very close to what you need (or at least give you things to search on). I've actually used this approach, so I can confirm that it does work. If you aren't using a database (i.e. if you won't need to save/load what the user puts in your appearing textbox) then it should simplify down. This should get you Googling though. Hope it helps!

-sf

EDIT: Per Chris' comment, I think:

```
function hideOnClick(){
  var d =  document.getElementById('<% =yourtextbox.ClientID %>');
  if(d.style.display == "none"){
     d.style.display = "inline";
  }else{
     d.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
```

might help you if all you need is the client-side javascript to toggle show/hide. All you'd need to do is attach it to your edit button.

Comment: Only slight problem is, what if they aren't using ASP?, and thats a lot of lines of code for a simple hide/unhide function that can be handled client-side only.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I guess he's left to utilize jQuery's ajax stuff. I thought the answer was okay given that he was searching for different ways to do this. The solution I've posted here allows for load/save functionality, as well as extensibility. Given that I use a store procedure to populate the grid, he would be able to put whatever he wanted from the users profile. If he wanted to save, the machinery is all there. I've edited to reflect what I think you were looking for :)